# If the distribution of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ depends on $f(Y)$, are the distributions of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ and on $f(Y)$ the same?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X,Y$ are random variables and the conditional distribution $X|Y$ depends on some measurable function of $Y$, which we will call $f, $is the distribution of $X|Y$ the same as $X|f(Y)$? In other words, do we have that:

$$
X|Y \sim X|f(Y)
$$

Comment: Yes, if the distribution of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ depends on $Y$ through $f(Y)$ only, then the distributions of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ and on $f(Y)$ coincide. To see this, note that the hypothesis is that, for every function $g$ there exists some function $h$ such that $$E(g(X)\mid Y)=h(f(Y))$$ Then, by the tower property, $$E(g(X)\mid f(Y))=E(E(g(X)\mid Y)\mid f(Y))=E(h(f(Y))\mid f(Y))=h(f(Y))$$ hence $$E(g(X)\mid Y)=E(g(X)\mid f(Y))$$ Since this holds for every function $g$, we proved that the distributions of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ and on $f(Y)$ coincide.

Comment: Could I ask why you introduced the function $g$ and why the the last line with the conditional expectations show that the distributions coincide? Is it a property of conditional expectations that shows the distributions hold almost surely?

Comment: Distributions are *characterized* by expectations in the sense that if $E(g(U))=E(g(V))$ for every $g$ then $U=V$ in distribution.

Comment: @Did Thanks, I have never seen that formulation, would you know where I might find more about this property to read about, say inside a textbook?

Comment: David Williams, *Probability with martingales*, first chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no in general, but there are instances where it may be the case. You can see this if you take for example $f\equiv 0$ or any function that takes $Y$ as input and gives very few information as output. If $X$ depends on some information contained in $Y$ but not in $f(Y)$ then the distributions, certainly differ. For the contrary see comments (your own comment) below.

Comment: What if we had that $X|Y \sim N(Y^2, 1)$ where $f(Y) = Y^2$, then in this case would we have that $X|Y \sim X|f(Y) \sim X|Y^2$?

Comment: Yes, in this case it would be the same.

Comment: Do you have any idea under what conditions my above statement would hold true or is there no unifying theme?

Comment: Is $f(Y)=0$ a counterexample? If the distribution of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ depends only on $0$, it does not depend on $Y$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent, hence indeed the distribution of $X$ conditionally on $Y$ and  conditionally on $0$ coincide.

Comment: @Did Yes, in this case, as in the case that user321627 gave, it is not a counterexample.

Comment: "The answer is no in general" Hmmm, any specific example where the answer would be "no"?

Comment: @Did I changed the title back to the original of the OP if you don't mind. If you want to answer another question you can do it by posting your own question and answering it.

Comment: @JimmyR. Is there a difference between what the OP's title mean and what the modified version you nullified was saying (except that the modified version was more precise)? If there are none, why did you see fit to revert? (And frankly I do not get your "If you want to answer another question", what are you talking about?)

Comment: "The answer is no in general" We still have no explanation for this (startling) statement. Do you plan to leave it as it is?